# protobuf-net code generator

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am incorporating Google Proto Buffers into my project and it is really nice how protoc.exe for windows generates header and source files for serialization/deserialization. I need protobuf.net code generator. So, for example if I a class Person, I first need to define it in the .proto file. Then when I run protoc.exe on it, it will give me the .h and .c files. But then manually, I have to do the following for the Person class:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set:}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class Address {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Line1 {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Line2 {get;set;}
}
```

And I want everything automated. So, technically I would want to give the .proto file for class Person and get the above output in return. I do NOT want to do manual work. I can write that tool myself. But if there is already a tool that is widely used, I would prefer to use that one instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a C# protobuf generator here:

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/ProtoGen

It can take protobin output from protoc.exe, or it can take .proto files and transparently call protoc for you, then converts the output to C#.
It is open source so if you need to tweak how it generates classes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5 has a grpc template so you can create a new project with `dotnet new grpc`. It has a grpc server included. If you modify the HelloRequest message in the greet.proto file in the generated project and compile again you will see that a `HelloRequest` class is newly generated.
The project references the [Grpc.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.AspNetCore) nuget package.

> Grpc.AspNetCore is a metapackage with references to:
>
> - Grpc.AspNetCore.Server: gRPC server library for .NET.
> - Grpc.Tools: Code-generation tooling package.
> - Google.Protobuf: Protobuf serialization library.

(see [Grpc.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.AspNetCore))