# Constructing a cs file from a proto file?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

This may seem really basic but I'm really new to C# so the google reference docs aren't that clear to me.

They instruct:

```
protoc --proto_path=bar --csharp_out=src --csharp_opt=base_namespace=Example player.proto
```

and their example is

```
protoc --proto_path=src --csharp_out=build/gen --csharp_opt=file_extension=.g.cs,base_namespace=Example src/foo.proto
```

So my list of basic questions is:

- For proto_path, is this starting from the top level of the program folder
- What is the 'bar' option, is it always 'src'?
- What is the 'src' option, is it always 'build/gen'?
- Is this copiable? '--csharp_opt=file_extension=.g.cs,base_namespace=MyProgram src/MyProtoFile.proto'

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452839/protobuf-net-code-generator/71385969#71385969) in a related question.

Answer (score 0):

> > For proto_path, is this starting from the top level of the program folder

--proto_path 
is where the proto files exist that you want converted to cs files.  This is relative to the protoc executable but may also be set to a specific location, e.g. --proto_path="C:/myprotofiles/"

> > What is the 'bar' option, is it always 'src'?

"bar" isn't an option.  "foo" and "bar" are commonly used as placeholders when giving generic instructions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)

> > What is the 'src' option, is it always 'build/gen'?

src is not an option.  src is a placeholder for a directory.  You will replace "src" with the directory containing your proto files.

--csharp_out is where you want the output C# files to go.  This is also relative to the protoc executable but may also be set to a specific location, e.g. --csharp_out="C:/mycsfiles/"

> > Is this copiable? '--csharp_opt=file_extension=.g.cs,base_namespace=MyProgram src/MyProtoFile.proto'

I'm not quite sure of your question here.  This is two parts.

--csharp_opt sets options.  This example is setting a file_extension to .g.cs (so output files will be somecsfile.g.cs) and also setting a base_namespace to "MyProgram" so all classes generated will be in a namespace called MyProgram.

"src/MyProtoFile.proto," or "src/foo.proto" in Google's example, is a proto file in the /src directory.  In our example we would replace this with "c:/myprotofiles/myprotofile.proto"

So, we'd have:

```
protoc --proto_path="C:/myprotofiles/" --csharp_out="C:/mycsfiles/" --csharp_opt=file_extension=.g.cs,base_namespace=MyProtoFileNamespace "c:/myprotofiles/myprotofile.proto"
```

Setting explicit paths isn't necessary but hopefully clarifies things (at least for Windows users!)